# Detailed sequence of disk access requests needed to update a file

Tags: unix, operating-system, inode

Could any one answer this question:

Describe the detailed sequence of disk access requests needed to update the 600th byte of file “test.txt” in the current directory. Assume file system blocks are 512 bytes long ( a single disk sector)

1. assuming an index-node structure
2. assuming an allocation-table structure

Comment: Is this homework, then you should perhaps add the respective tag :)

Comment: nopes...this is not homework. I came across this question on internet and have an exam. So just wanted to know the answer.